# Nhibernate 2.1 and mysql 5 - InvalidCastException on Setup

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

I am trying to use NHibernate with Spring.Net und mySQL 5. However, when setting up the connection and creating the SessionFactoryObject, I get this InvalidCastException:

NHibernate seems to cast MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection to System.Data.Common.DbConnection which causes the exception.

```
System.InvalidCastException wurde nicht behandelt.
  Message="Das Objekt des Typs \"MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection\" kann nicht in Typ \"System.Data.Common.DbConnection\" umgewandelt werden."
  Source="NHibernate"
  StackTrace:
       bei NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.Prepare() in c:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Tool\hbm2ddl\SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.cs:Zeile 25.
       bei NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.GetReservedWords(Dialect dialect, IConnectionHelper connectionHelper) in c:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Tool\hbm2ddl\SchemaMetadataUpdater.cs:Zeile 43.
       bei NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaMetadataUpdater.Update(ISessionFactory sessionFactory) in c:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Tool\hbm2ddl\SchemaMetadataUpdater.cs:Zeile 17.
       bei NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners) in c:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Impl\SessionFactoryImpl.cs:Zeile 169.
       bei NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() in c:\CSharp\NH\nhibernate\src\NHibernate\Cfg\Configuration.cs:Zeile 1090.
       bei OrmTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Max\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\OrmTest\OrmTest\Program.cs:Zeile 24.
       bei System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
       bei System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       bei Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

I am using the programmatically setup approach in order to get a quick NHibernate Setup. Here is the setup Code:

```
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            Dictionary props = new Dictionary();
            props.Add("dialect", "NHibernate.Dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
            props.Add("connection.provider", "NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider");
            props.Add("connection.driver_class", "NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver");
            props.Add("connection.connection_string", "Server=localhost;Database=orm_test;User ID=root;Password=password");
            props.Add("proxyfactory.factory_class", "NHibernate.ByteCode.Spring.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Spring");
            config.AddProperties(props);
            config.AddFile("Person.hbm.xml");
            ISessionFactory factory = config.BuildSessionFactory();
            ISession session = factory.OpenSession();
```

Is something missing? I downloaded the current mysql Connector from the mysql Website.

Comment: Weird - I've just checked the source, and it certainly does derive from DbConnection...

Comment: Hm, so... what am I todo now in order to get NHibernate and mysql up running?

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me, I downloaded accidently a wrong mysql connector and not the latest version: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.0.html

Sorry!